How to set next approver in bill payment approval workflow?
I have created workflow for bill payment approval. there will be 2 approvers, first controler and next vp. once user creates bill payment and submit for approval controler role user should set in the next approver field on the bill payment record. once controler approves the bill payment, next approver should set will be vp user.
